# Is that possible for WebBluetooth to send beacon

Tags: ibeacon, eddystone, web-bluetooth

I am wondering,
Is that possible if i open up a web browser and walking with my phone which sends web bluetooth beacon so that others can discover me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.   Web browsers on Android and iOS do it support advertising using Web Bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.